# Positioning of a HTML checkbox in Django Admin Form

Tags: html, css, django

I created a HTML [checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ez4C.png) which looks like a button. 
I use it in a `Django Admin Form` in order to select all [BooleanField](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWVeJ.png). It works very well but I don't know how to put the `checkbox` above the `Booleans`.

The `checkbox` is in `change_form.html` which is specific to this form and I can put this one on top or bottom of the form but not in specific field. How can I put my `checkbox` on the field I want ?

Maybe with `forms.css` but I do not succeed to custom this file. The path `"{% static "admin/css/forms.css" %}"` must confuse me. I put `forms.css` file in `myproject/myapp/static/admin/css/forms.css` and that doesn't work. Any idea ?